# Remove, replace special characters when importing csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, shiny, utf-8

When importing data in csv format, some observations contain special characters as shown in the image below.
[image]
I would like to know how I can eliminate them, replace them or any method that allows me to work with them. Since in Shiny it throws me the following error:

```
Warning: Error in sub: input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
  [No stack trace available]
```

I tried this code but it had no effect on the data.

```
data %>%
  mutate_all(funs(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .)))
```

I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: What exactly do you consider a "special character"? you need to make sure you know what encoding was used to store your character data and specify that encoding when reading the data. It's not really possible to tell what's going on from an image.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details all I can offer is an example that might help you based on the [janitor](https://garthtarr.github.io/meatR/janitor.html) package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

test_df <- tibble("test_µ" = c(1,2,3), 
                  "test_%23ñ" = c("fesfñUaâ", "fesââçç", "ËÔ†"), 
                  "test_normal" = c("wordsñ", "£Ÿüõ", "ÁÑ¿F"))

test_df
#> A tibble: 3 x 3
#>  test_µ `test_%23ñ` test_normal
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      
#>1      1 fesfñUaâ    wordsñ     
#>2      2 fesââçç     £Ÿüõ       
#>3      3 ËÔ†         ÁÑ¿F      

cleaned_df <- test_df %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ make_clean_names(.)))

cleaned_df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  test_m test_percent_23n test_normal
  <chr>  <chr>            <chr>      
1 x1     fesfn_uaa        wordsn     
2 x2     fesaacc          yuo        
3 x3     eo               an_f
```